# Prove if $|z| =1,$ with $z \neq 1$, then Im$(\frac{1}{i-z}) = - \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove if $|z| =1,$ with $z \neq 1$, then Im$(\frac{1}{i-z}) = - \frac{1}{2}$.

So far, we have the following: we can let $z = x+iy$ and $|z|=1 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x^2+y^2$

So $z$ is in the set of points satisfying $x^2+y^2=1$. What we want to show is that $\frac{1}{i-z}$'s vertical displacement from the origin gives it a position analagous to $e^{i \cdot \frac{7 \pi}{6}}$ or $e^{i \cdot \frac{11 \pi}{6}}$ since $\sin \frac{7 \pi}{6} = \sin \frac{11 \pi}{6} = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Does anyone have any insight on this problem?  We know

$$\frac{1}{i-z}= \frac{1}{i-x-iy} = \frac{1}{-x+i(-y-1)}$$

Maybe we could say something like

$$\Big| \frac{1}{i-z} \Big| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(-y-1)^2}} = \dots ?$$

Am I headed in the right direction? How can we deduce that Im$(\frac{1}{i-z})= - \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Let $z=x+yi$, since $Im(t)=(t-\bar t)/2$ then $Im(\frac{1}{i-z})=(\frac{1}{i-z}-\frac{1}{-i-\bar z})/2=(\frac{1}{i-x-yi}-\frac{1}{-i-x+yi})/2$, can you continue from here?

Comment: You can write $\frac{1}{i-z}=\frac{-i-\bar{z}}{(i-z)(-i-\bar{z})}=\frac{-i-\bar{z}}{2+i(z-\bar{z})}$. Let $\mu=2+i(z-\bar{z})\in\mathbb{R}$. $Im\left(\frac{1}{i-z}\right)=\frac{1}{\mu}\left[\frac{-i-\bar{z}-(i-z)}{2i}\right]=$...

Comment: @cheesefoot A minor point is that I believe your $z \neq 1$ should be $z \neq i$ instead, to ensure $\frac{1}{i - z}$ is well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could do it manually

From $$\frac{1}{i-z}= \frac{1}{i-x-iy} = \frac{1}{-x+i(1-y)}$$
You have $$\frac{1}{i-z} = \frac{1}{-x+i(1-y)} = \frac{-x -i(1-y)}{[-x+i(1-y)][-x-i(1-y)]} $$
After simplifying you have $$\frac{-x -i(1-y)}{x^2 + y^2 -2y + 1} $$,
Which is $$\frac{-x -i(1-y)}{ 2-2y} $$
Separate real and imaginary part and you get the result

Comment: I do like your description of this as "doing it manually" :)

Comment: This is so amazing. I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!